# How to modify bibstyle?

Tags: bibliographies

I have a small problem with the humanbio bibliographystyle. How can I say that I do not want to have the journals printed in italics?

Thank you very much

Nevs

Comment: Welcome to TX.SE! Please show us a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) !

Answer (score 2):

copy `humanbio.bst` to a new file (say `myhumanbio.bst`) in the same directory as your document, then assuming your entry is of `@article`  the italic comes from `emphasise` so change

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output              % special for
  output.year.check                 % apalike
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

to

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output              % special for
  output.year.check                 % apalike
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

and use `\bibliographystyle{myhumanbio}` in your document.

The original will be at a location like

```
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/beebe/humanbio.bst
```